# Why can't I host my flask file on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, flask-restful

I deployed my entire GitHub repo which contains both my frontend (in react native) and backend (flask code). I tried a test.py file to see if Heroku is hosting my backend properly but it seems like the base URL could not find anything (note: it worked all fine when tested locally).

I am aware Heroku doesn't host react native, so my Heroku page just shows the Welcome to your app! page. Also, how would Heroku know which is my main flask file?

Have tried testing the flask code locally and it works. Do I perhaps need to add something to my route as there are other files deployed too? Sorry I'm very new to this!